# how to commentmultiple lines with awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a perl program which I am downloading and using in a docker file.

This program is calling `tbl2asn` but I do not need the output and this part runs very long. Therefore, I want to comment a few lines out of this perl program.

```
runcmd(
  "tbl2asn -V b -a r10k -l paired-ends -M n -N 1 -y 'Annotated using $EXE $VERSION from $URL' -Z".
  " \Q$outdir/$prefix.err\E -i \Q$outdir/$prefix.fsa\E 2> /dev/null"
);
delfile("$outdir/errorsummary.val");
delfile( map { "$outdir/$prefix.$_" } qw(dr fixedproducts ecn val) );

msg("Repairing broken .GBK output that tbl2asn produces...");
runcmd("sed 's/COORDINATES: profile/COORDINATES:profile/' < \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbf\E > \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbk\E");
delfile("$outdir/$prefix.gbf");
```

These are the lines I want to comment and at least this line `"tbl2asn -V b -a r10k -l paired-ends -M n -N 1 -y 'Annotated using $EXE $VERSION from $URL' -Z".` only occurs once in the perl program.

How can I use awk or sed to comment this line via a regex, one before and eight lines after?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

Sample `file.pl`:

```
some text
runcmd(
  "tbl2asn -V b -a r10k -l paired-ends -M n -N 1 -y 'Annotated using $EXE $VERSION from $URL' -Z".
  " \Q$outdir/$prefix.err\E -i \Q$outdir/$prefix.fsa\E 2> /dev/null"
);
delfile("$outdir/errorsummary.val");
delfile( map { "$outdir/$prefix.$_" } qw(dr fixedproducts ecn val) );

msg("Repairing broken .GBK output that tbl2asn produces...");
runcmd("sed 's/COORDINATES: profile/COORDINATES:profile/' < \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbf\E > \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbk\E");
delfile("$outdir/$prefix.gbf");
some text
```

---

```
awk '/"tbl2asn -V b .+ -Z"\.$/{ n = NR + 9 }NR <= n{ rec = "#"rec }
     rec{ print rec }{ rec = $0 }
     END{ print rec }' file.pl
```

The output:

```
some text
#runcmd(
#  "tbl2asn -V b -a r10k -l paired-ends -M n -N 1 -y 'Annotated using $EXE $VERSION from $URL' -Z".
#  " \Q$outdir/$prefix.err\E -i \Q$outdir/$prefix.fsa\E 2> /dev/null"
#);
#delfile("$outdir/errorsummary.val");
#delfile( map { "$outdir/$prefix.$_" } qw(dr fixedproducts ecn val) );
#
#msg("Repairing broken .GBK output that tbl2asn produces...");
#runcmd("sed 's/COORDINATES: profile/COORDINATES:profile/' < \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbf\E > \Q$outdir/$prefix.gbk\E");
#delfile("$outdir/$prefix.gbf");
some text
```